# iOS dark light mode not updating UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode12, ios-darkmode

I am facing problem with a iOS project with Xcode 12.3. App is designed for both light and dark mode and it is working fine if we are changing light/dark mode while app is closed but if send app in background and change mode and resume app then current UIViewController not updating dark/light mode. You can check that in below.

[image: http://g.recordit.co/0LtJsLLkfe.gif]

Comment: How are you detecting the light-dark mode change?

Comment: can you try to override this function to check this is calling after you resume app. override func updateLayer() {
   self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.textBackgroundColor.cgColor

   // Other updates.
}

Comment: I am not detecting mode change, almost all element are changing color in automatically but some element those are not changing automatic for those I am setting color manually in viewDidLoad with code `if(traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark){` and changing element color.

Answer (score 1):

When User Interface Style is changed then system call `func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?)`
this delegate methods

please refresh your programatic assigned colors in this methods

```
   override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
        if(traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark){
            // set your Dark UI
        } else {
            // set your Light UI
        }
    }
```